# Sony Flash 'AM' vs 'M' notation

Tags: flash, sony

I'm shopping for some used flashes, and I'm curious the subtle difference between a couple of models that come up in search hits.

```
Sony HVL-F43M
Sony HVL-F43AM
Sony HVL-F32M
Sony HVL-F42AM
```

Here's a closeup example of some labeling differences, maybe it's just a regional thing? What's the significance of the `M` vs `AM`
[image: Sony HVL F43AM vs F43M]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The older AM models had the [iISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IISO_flash_shoe)/Auto-lock foot that preceded the Multi-Interface foot and shoe. Minolta introduced it in 1988 and Sony continued with it on some (but not all) of their cameras until 2012. Some cameras that used the auto-lock shoe were the α33, α55, α58, and NEX 7. Some people called it the "reversed" hotshoe.

Pictured below is a camera shoe with which the AM model flashes are compatible.

[image: iISO shoe]

The newer M models have feet for the [Sony Multi Interface Shoe (MI or MI S)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi_Interface_Shoe). Sony cameras since 2012 use this shoe.

[image: MI shoe]

There are adapters available from Sony that allow using flashes with one foot with cameras with the other shoe. Any automatic capability of the flash is maintained. [ADP-MAA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0097DFTDY) allows one to attach an iISO flash to a Multi Interface camera/shoe. [ADP-AMA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0099YS6WW) allows one to attach a Multi Interface flash to an iISO camera/shoe.

Answer (score 2):

The "M" model is newer and is designed to work with Sony's "[Multi Interface Shoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi_Interface_Shoe)", which is a proprietary hotshoe design Sony came out with in 2012. So the "M" designation probably relates to that.

There is a side-by-side comparison of the F43M and AM models on B&H's site [here](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/compare/Sony_HVL-F60M_vs_Sony_HVL-F43M_vs_Sony_HVL-F43AM/BHitems/898312-REG_984435-REG_767660-REG).  The AM models seem to be discontinued and the M models are much more full-featured units.